# Send a JSON with file in it to Flask BE using axios and React FE

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, axios

I was wondering if there is a way to send an object with files in it to the backend. The purpose is, I have a list of users and I want to send their name, address, etc. along with the resume they upload. The form I want is this:

```
{ name: ..., address: ..., resume: File Object, ... }
```

I am sending it using `Formdata()` with the content type of `multi-part/form-data` but my request shows it as `data: object Object`. I cannot read it because of this. If I jsonify it, then I can see the data, but the files show up as an empty object. Is there any way to send in the form above? Or, is there a way I can read it in my Flask backend? I want it in the form above so that it is easy for me to extract the resume for each user in the backend. If I separate out the resume from the object, I will need a way to map it to the user. That will also require me to figure out how to send the user id and the resume file together.